# Mp4/H2.64 Video playback using gstreamer 1.0 is not happening in Virtual box. (Audio is hearable)

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, gstreamer, mp4, h.264

On using gst-launch-1.0, we are getting the following error ,

```
#gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/vysakhav/video.mp4 
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=   (null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=  (null)
Got context from element 'eglglessink0': gst.egl.EGLDisplay=context,    display=(GstEGLDisplay)NULL;
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
Redistribute latency...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
```

On executing this command, launched eglglesssink and audio is hearable. But not able to see the video.

Virtual Box: Version 5.1.2 r108956
Vbox hosted in Windows10. (Ububtu 14.04)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to install a software H.264 decoder element for Gstreamer. Like `gstreamer1.0-libav` which should include the FFMPEG decoders.

Your pipeline tries to access the the GPU hardware decoder which is unavailable when running inside Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Installing nvidia driver by following command, movie is shown on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-384
```